# How can i write dictionary keys and values against one placeholder in a file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I am trying to validate a json file and after validation i want to write results on a new file. 
For that i am using json module in python. I have a dictionary object named schema that holds all the keys and values. If i print it i get the result as shown below

```
{'deviceId': 'String', 'userId': 'String', 'regTime': 'Number', 'timestamp': 'String', 'cardiac': 'Number', 'gyro': 'array', 'acc': 'array'}
```

I want to write this whole schema result in a file against a place holder @schema_result. Such that it looks like below

```
deviceId String

userId String

regTime Number

timestamp String

cardiac Number

gyro array

acc array
```

Currently i am writing this schema object like this

```
def filing(schema, file_name): #a function that takes schema dictionary and name of file where to write
config = open(file_name, 'w')
for line in open('schema.json', 'r'):
    for key,value in schema.items():
        print(key+" "+value+"\n")
        line = line.replace('@schema_result', str(key+" "+value+"\n"))
    config.write(line)
```

This only results in replacing the first key and value against @schema_result. As the schema object is dictionary i am unable to add next items because after first iteration it will replace @schema_result with the first key and value and next time it can not find @schema_result as it is already replaced.

Current result is like below

```
deviceId String #against @schema_placeholder in first iteration
```

How can i write all the key and values against one placeholder in a file

There are two files

- `schema.json` is the file that contains the place holder @schema_result
- This `@schema_result` is replaced by the output in a new file which is `file_name` variable

Comment: Can you present a sample input file? That's necessary to form a [mcve].

Comment: is your `schema.txt` a json file? why aren't you loading it as json object?

Comment: @iBug I have added my input file in question

Comment: @SufiyanGhori yes it should be schema.json, i just used schema.txt as an example here. I have changed it in sample code

Comment: where is `@schema_result` in the file?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori please check my latest edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop to read every item from the `schema` dictionary, you can use list comprehension with `join` to join entire dictionary key values together and then write it to a file,

```
schema = {'deviceId': 'String', 'userId': 'String', 'regTime': 'Number', 'timestamp': 'String', 'cardiac': 'Number', 'gyro': 'array', 'acc': 'array'}


formatted_schema = ["{} {}\n".format(k,v) for k,v in schema.items()]
formatted_schema = ''.join(formatted_schema)

# output,

deviceId String
userId String
regTime Number
timestamp String
cardiac Number
gyro array
acc array
```

now you can simply write `formatted_schema` to file replacing it with `@schema_result`

Comment: Thank you so much it is working perfectly fine for the required output. just asking one another question if i wanted to modify the format of the output how to do that? like adding \t at the start. thank you so much again.

Comment: you can simply format your string, please have a read, https://pyformat.info/